# AJAX Error: POST http://localhost/upload/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have been searching the net and testing for hours now but I could not pinpoint what the error is. So, I am looking for your kind help here. I followed step by step multiple files upload tutorial with the drag & drop functionality but I got the error message as mentioned in the title (and the line of code that throws the error is xmlhttp.send(data); ). 
File upload.js has this function:

```
(function(o) {
    "use strict";

    var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

    ajax = function(data) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var uploaded;

        xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                if(this.status === 200){
                    uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    if(typeof o.options.finished === 'function'){
                        o.options.finished(uploaded);
                    }   
                } else {
                    if(typeof o.options.error === 'function'){
                        o.options.error();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    };

    getFormData = function(source) {
        var data = new FormData();
        var i;

        for(i = 0; i < source.length; i = i + 1) {
            data.append('files[]', source[i]);
        }
        return data;
    };

    o.uploader = function(options) {
        o.options = options;
        if(o.options.files !== undefined) {
            ajax(getFormData(o.options.files));
        }
    };
}());
```

and the global.js file has this code:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');
    var uploadsFinished = document.getElementById('uploads-finished');

    var startUpload = function(files) {
        app.uploader({
            files: files,
            Processor: 'upload.php',

            finished: function(data){
                var x;
                var uploadedElement;
                var uploadedAnchor;
                var uploadStatus;

                for (x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1) {
                    currFile = data[x];
                    uploadedElement = document.createElement('div');
                    uploadedElement.className = 'uploaded-console-upload';

                    uploadedAnchor = document.getElementById('a');
                    uploadedAnchor.textContent = currFile.name;

                    if(currFile.uploaded) {
                        uploadedAnchor.href = 'uploads/' + currFile.file;
                    }

                    uploadedStatus = document.createElement('span');
                    uploadedStatus.textContent = currFile.uploaded ? 'uploaded' : 'Failed';
                    uploadedElement.appendChild(uploadedAnchor);
                    uploadedElement.appendChild(uploadedStatus);
                    uploadsFinished.appendChild(uploadedElement);

                }

                uploadsFinished.className = '';
            },

            error: function() {
                //console.log('There was an error');
            }
        });
    };

    //Standard form upload
    document.getElementById('standard-upload').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var standardUploadFiles = document.getElementById('standard-upload-files').files;
        e.preventDefault();
        startUpload();

    });

    //Drop funtionality
    dropZone.ondrop = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.className = 'upload-console-drop';
        startUpload(e.dataTransfer.files);
    };

    dropZone.ondragover = function() {
        this.className = 'upload-console-drop drop';
        return false;
    };

    dropZone.ondragleave = function() {
        this.className = 'upload-console-drop';
        return false;
    };

}());
```

Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest does not have a property options. This is why you're are returning undefined. Try this: let a = new XMLHttpRequest(); console.log(a.options).

Order of operations is important here. Make sure if you are defining this property it's defined BEFORE it's called. Otherwise it's undefined.

Comment: The fact that you are are getting `undefined` in the URL (`http://localhost/upload/undefined`) tells me how you're creating the URL is wrong. How is `o.options.processor` getting created?

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. Your answers helped to find the error. a.options does exist, if you look at the o.uploader function, you will see it there. The problem was processor was undefiled because it was spelled Processor. Thank you again to you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`o.options.processor` was defined as `Processor` and when it was called back later in the code, it was referred to as `processor` (changing from `Processor` to `processor`) solved the case. Thank you guys with your comments that helped me to find the error.